# Filtering SharePoint lists client side based on date range

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to filter SharePoint list on Created date column based on date range defined(based on From date and To date which item is added to list)?

This should be achieved with our using SharePoint designer and using only Client side coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following caml Query in Client side scripting.

```
     <Query>
        <Where>
          <And>
            <Geq>
             <FieldRef Name="Created" />
              <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2016-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value>
           </Geq>
           <Leq>
            <FieldRef Name="Created" />
            <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2016-12-31T15:56:29Z</Value>
           </Leq>
         </And>
       </Where>
    </Query>
```

Following is the complete code(JSOM)

```
  function queryListItems() {           
     var context = new SP.ClientContext();           
     var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List name');           
     var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();             
     caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where> <And><Geq><FieldRef Name="Created" /><Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2016-01-01T15:55:52Z</Value></Geq><Leq><FieldRef Name="Created" />
                       <Value IncludeTimeValue="TRUE" Type="DateTime">2016-12-31T15:56:29Z</Value></Leq></And></Where></Query></View>");             
     returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
     context.load(returnedItems);             
     context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
  }       

  function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {             
     var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();
      while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
          //get current using var item=enumerator.get_current();         
    }        
   }  
      //This function fires when the query fails  
    function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
       console.error(args.get_message());       
     }
```

reference 
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/retrieve-the-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript/